# How to update saved input value in local storage when it is showed and edited in another input element?

Tags: javascript, input, addeventlistener

I am creating "Todo" list.
There is one main 'input', 'type=text', field and from there the 'input.value' is stored in the 'localStorage', and after that the data is retrieved, parsed and dynamically presented in another 'input' fields.

So, when user wants to edit the todo input that has been previusly created, it is easy to accesses it, but how to save the data to the 'localStorage'? There is not any button that user will click on.

Bottom line, I need to grab that changed text and replace it with the existing one in the local storage so when the page loads again that change is permanent.

Which event listener should I use?
So far I tried with "blur", "onchange", "oninput"... but the function is not returning anything.

Comment: Set up a `change` event handler on the `input` and set the `localStorage` value there. And, always add the code you are working with to your question. When you say your function isn't returning anything, that doesn't tell us much. Why should the function return anything? Setting a value is not the same thing as returning a value.

Comment: Good point. Thank you for the comment. In future, I will always provide the reference code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible solution may be something like :

```
const yourInput = document.getelementbyid('yourInputId');
yourInput.addEventListener('change', (event) => {
  localStorage.setItem(keyName, event.target.value);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Ciao, you could try to use `onInput` event like this:

```js
function edValueKeyPress() {
    var edValue = document.getElementById("edValue");
    var s = edValue.value;

    var lblValue = document.getElementById("lblValue");
    lblValue.innerText = "The text box contains: " + s;
}
```

```html
<input id="edValue" type="text" onInput="edValueKeyPress()"><br>
<span id="lblValue">The text box contains: </span>
```

Comment: First, don't use inline event attributes - always do your event handling in JavaScript with `.addEventListener()`. Next, the `change` event is the better approach here. Finally, use `.textContent`, rather than `.innerText`.

Comment: @ScottMarcus why "the change event is the better approach here" ?

Comment: Because OP doesn't want to set a value into `localStorage` at every keystroke of input. He wants to set the updated value after it's been updated.

Comment: @ScottMarcus  Ok but `change` event will be triggered only when input will be unblurred. I'm wrong?

Comment: That's right and exactly what the OP needs here. If `input` is used, it will fire every time there is any kind of input on the element, so if I type "Scott" into the field, the event will fire 5 times and that's not what the OP wants.